# Unresolved Reference 'Object' problem with getting variables from class

Tags: python, class

Hi everyone I am having an unresolved reference error. My code looks like this

```
class Main:
    PhysicalDmg = 0
    MagicDmg = 0
    dmgTaken = 100
    Health = 100

class HeroSelection(Main):
    dyl = Dylan()                    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ERROR LINE
    user_hero_selection = input("choose your fighter")
    if user_hero_selection == "Dylan":
        print(dyl.stats)

class Dylan(Main, HeroSelection):
    print("character DYLAN")
    stats = ["Dylan", 24, 6.5, 210, "Physical", 2]
```

I am trying to print the 'stats' array from the Dylan Class into the user_hero_selection class. But the Pycharm keeps on giving me the error: unresolved reference 'Dylan'. I've been struggling on this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Python reads a file from top to bottom and runs all the global level code which includes class level definitions in your code.

Since `Dylan()` is a class level definition of the `HeroSelection` class, it means it will run when python runs this script, however, since `class Dylan` is defined after the class level definition, it does not know that `Dylan` exists yet.

It also looks like if you move `class Dylan` above `HeroSelection` you have the same problem, since you reference `HeroSelection` as a base class of `Dylan`

A quick fix is to put an initializer `__init__` for `HeroSelection`

```
class HeroSelection(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        dyl = Dylan()
        user_hero_selection = input("choose your fighter")
        if user_hero_selection == "Dylan":
            print(dyl.stats)
```

However, not sure how you are using this classes.

*More on execution model and resolution found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) and class definition and instances [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=class#scopes-and-namespaces-example)*

Answer (score 0):

You are putting code into the initialization of a Class, so any variables you set there will be available to all instances of a class (consider that for every `class Main:` you can have many `main1 = Main()` and they will all see the same `PhysicalDmg`, whereas what you probably wanted was something like `def __init__(): self.PhysicalDmg` which sets the variable on the specific instance `main1`

consider this approach:

```py
class Stats:
  def __init__(self, pd=0, md=0, dt=100, h=100):
    self.PhysicalDmg = pd
    self.MagicDmg = 0
    self.dmgTaken = dt
    self.Health = h
  def __str__(self):
    return [self.PhysicalDmg, self.MagicDmg, self.dmgTaken, self.Health]

# this doesnt need to be a class
def HeroSelection():
    dyl = Dylan()
    user_hero_selection = raw_input("choose your fighter") # use raw input in py27
    if user_hero_selection.strip() == "Dylan":
        print(str(dyl.stats))

class Dylan(Main):
  def __init__(self):
    print("character DYLAN")
    self.name = "Dylan"
    self.stats = Stats(24, 6.5, 210, "Physical", 2)

HeroSelection()
```

Comment: actually i realize the array had other data in it, but you can get the idea of how to use classes from this i hope